# Failed to write session data in express

Tags: node.js, express

Sometimes the data I'm storing in a session won't be saved.
The next request the data is just **gone**.

The way I'm storing the data in the session is very straight-forward:

```
// Store the complete user data in the session
req.session.user = user;

// Redirect to the correct url
res.redirect(redirectUrl);
```

As you can see, I do a redirect immediately afterwards.

I did have an entry that contained *a lot* of data.
When I removed that entry, everything started working again.

So now I wonder:

- Does this happen because the object is "too big" for a session or
- because there is some race condition with the saving of the session?

As far as I can tell, there is no asynchronous function that lets you save the session before doing a redirect...

Answer (score 0):

You can rule out whether the issue is the first function completing by wrapping both of them in async.series: https://github.com/caolan/async#series